# When writing Junit test case using mockito for findById() JPA method I am getting error as java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

Tags: java, jpa, junit, spring-data-jpa, mockito

Since findById method of JPA has return type as optional and I am using get method to get the exact value, I am unable to implement unit test.

My Service code:

public class LobbyService {

```
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LobbyService.class);

private final LobbyRepository lobbyRepository;
private final UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public LobbyService(@Qualifier("lobbyRepository") LobbyRepository lobbyRepository, @Qualifier("userRepository") UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.lobbyRepository = lobbyRepository;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

public Lobby createLobby(Lobby newLobby){

    checkIfLobbyExist(newLobby);
    lobbyRepository.save(newLobby);

    return newLobby;

}

public void updateStatusOfLobby(long id, int status){
    Lobby lobby = getLobby(id);
    lobby.setStatus(status);
    saveOrUpdate(lobby);
}

public void saveOrUpdate(Lobby updateLobby){
    lobbyRepository.save(updateLobby);
}

public List<LobbyGetDTO> getAllLobbies(){
    List<Lobby> lobbyList = this.lobbyRepository.findAll();
    List<LobbyGetDTO> lobbyGetDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Lobby tempLobby:lobbyList){
        LobbyGetDTO lobbyGetDTO = DTOMapper.INSTANCE.convertEntityToLobbyGetDTO(tempLobby);
        lobbyGetDTOList.add(lobbyGetDTO);
    }
    return lobbyGetDTOList;
}

public void removePlayerFromLobby(long id, long userId){
    Lobby lobby = getLobby(id);
    String baseErrorMessage = "This player id is invalid. Please provide proper id";
    if(lobby.getPlayerIds().contains(userId)){
        lobby.getPlayerIds().remove(userId);
    }
    else{
        throw new LobbyException(baseErrorMessage);
    }

    saveOrUpdate(lobby);
}

public void addPlayerToLobby(long id, long userId){
    Lobby lobby = getLobby(id);

    if(lobby.getStatus()==1){
        throw new LobbyException("Game is in progress. You can't join lobby in the middle of the game. Please try later");
    }

    //Checking if the user exists before adding the user to lobby
    userRepository.findById(userId)
            .orElseThrow(
                    () -> new LobbyException(String.format("User with id: %d doesn't exist", userId))
            );
    String baseErrorMessage = "The lobby cannot have more than 7 player. Please join different lobby";

    //Size of lobby is limited to maximum of 7 players.
    if(lobby.getPlayerIds().size()>=7){
        throw new LobbyException(baseErrorMessage);
    }

    //Player should be unique in the lobby
    if(lobby.getPlayerIds().contains(userId)){
        baseErrorMessage = "Player already exists in the lobby";
        throw new LobbyException(baseErrorMessage);
    }
    lobby.getPlayerIds().add(userId);
    saveOrUpdate(lobby);
}

public Lobby getLobby(Long id){

    Lobby lobby = this.lobbyRepository.findById(id).get();

    String baseErrorMessage = "The lobby %d doesn't exist. Please check the lobby which you are joining";
    if(null == lobby){
        throw new LobbyException(baseErrorMessage);
    }
    return lobby;
}

public void checkIfLobbyExist(Lobby lobbyToBeCreated) {
    /*
    This method checks the uniqueness of the lobby by lobby name. If the lobby with the same name
    exists then it should not be created.
     */
    Lobby newLobby = lobbyRepository.findByName(lobbyToBeCreated.getName());

    String baseErrorMessage = "The provided %s is not unique. Therefore, the lobby could not be created!";
    if (null != newLobby) {
        throw new LobbyException(String.format(baseErrorMessage, "lobby name"));
    }
}
```

}

My Junit code:

```
public class LobbyServiceTest {


@Mock
LobbyRepository lobbyRepository;

@Mock
UserRepository userRepository;

@InjectMocks
LobbyService lobbyService;

private User testUser;
private Lobby lobbyTest;

@BeforeEach
public void setupLobby(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    lobbyTest = new Lobby();

    lobbyTest.setName("testLobby");
    lobbyTest.setHostPlayerId(1L);

    testUser = new User();
    testUser.setId(1L);
    testUser.setName("testName");
    testUser.setUsername("testUsername");

    // when -> any object is being save in the userRepository -> return the dummy testUser
    Mockito.when(userRepository.save(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(testUser);

    Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.save(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(lobbyTest);

}

@Test
public void createdLobby_validInputs_success(){
    Lobby createdLobby = lobbyService.createLobby(lobbyTest);

    Mockito.verify(lobbyRepository, Mockito.times(1)).save(Mockito.any());
    assertEquals(createdLobby.getId(),lobbyTest.getId());
    assertEquals(createdLobby.getName(),lobbyTest.getName());
    assertEquals(createdLobby.getHostPlayerId(),lobbyTest.getHostPlayerId());
}

@Test
public void createdLobbyExist_Exception(){
    lobbyService.createLobby(lobbyTest);

    Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.findByName(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(lobbyTest);

    assertThrows(LobbyException.class, ()->lobbyService.createLobby(lobbyTest));
}

@Test
public void addUserToLobbyWhenGameGoingOn(){

    lobbyTest.setStatus(1);
    lobbyService.createLobby(lobbyTest);

    Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.findById(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.ofNullable(lobbyTest));
    assertThrows(LobbyException.class,()->lobbyService.addPlayerToLobby(1L,1L));


}

@Test
public void addUserToLobby(){

    List<Long> playerList  = new ArrayList<>();
    Long[] longList = new Long[]{2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L};
    Collections.addAll(playerList,longList);
    lobbyTest.setPlayerIds(playerList);
    lobbyService.createLobby(lobbyTest);


    //Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.getOne(anyLong())).thenReturn(lobbyTest);
    Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(lobbyTest);
    Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(java.util.Optional.ofNullable(testUser));
    Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.save(Mockito.any(Lobby.class))).thenReturn(lobbyTest);
    lobbyService.addPlayerToLobby(1L,1L);
    assertEquals(lobbyTest.getPlayerIds().size(),7);

}

@Test
public void addExistingUserToLobby(){


    List<Long> playerList  = new ArrayList<>();
    Long[] longList = new Long[]{1L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L};
    Collections.addAll(playerList,longList);
    lobbyTest.setPlayerIds(playerList);
    lobbyService.createLobby(lobbyTest);

    //Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.getOne(anyLong())).thenReturn(lobbyTest);
    Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(lobbyTest);
    Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(testUser));
    Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.save(Mockito.any(Lobby.class))).thenReturn(lobbyTest);
    assertThrows(LobbyException.class,()->lobbyService.addPlayerToLobby(1L,1L));


}

@Test
public void addMoreThanSevenPlayerToLobby(){

    List<Long> playerList  = new ArrayList<>();
    Long[] longList = new Long[]{1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L};
    Collections.addAll(playerList,longList);
    lobbyTest.setPlayerIds(playerList);
    lobbyService.createLobby(lobbyTest);

    //Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.getOne(anyLong())).thenReturn(lobbyTest);
    Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(lobbyTest);
    Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(testUser));
    Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.save(Mockito.any(Lobby.class))).thenReturn(lobbyTest);
    assertThrows(LobbyException.class,()->lobbyService.addPlayerToLobby(1L,8L));

}
```

}

Error Message:

```
No value present
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:148)
```

I don't want to change my return type to Optional for findById. If there is any turnaround to write test in the current scenario?

Comment: and lobbyTest is?

Comment: Lobbytest was defined earlier as Lobby object in 

 @BeforeEach
    public void setupLobby() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `findById(id)` method to `getOne(id)` as below -

```
Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.getOne(anyLong())).thenReturn(lobbyTest);
```

And changed my test case to -

```
Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.getOne(anyLong())).thenReturn(lobbyTest);
```

Its working fine now.

Comment: But it's a completely different method which returns not the real entities but their references and loads them on demand. This can lead to unexpected behavior of your app. So it's probably not what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your test code with:

`Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(lobbyTest));`

Comment: Tried below code as suggested-

Mockito.when(lobbyRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(lobbyTest));

It also gave same exception.

Comment: Very strange. Could you upload the whole source code of Service and its test class (especially with signatures of classes, you may omit other methods if you want)? Maybe something else is missing there.

Answer (score 0):

You must mock both lobbyRepository.findById() and id to test. In your test case, do:

```
Lobby mockedLobby = getConcreteLobby();
Optional<Lobby> optionalLobby = Optional.of(mockedLobby);
when(lobbyRepository.findbyId(anyLong())).thenReturn(optionalLobby);
```

There are other approaches, but this probably will make it for your scenario.

One more thing: you should not test an Optional as you did. You must assure the code returns an Optional - empty or not -, and deal with it testing for Optional.isPresent(). In your case, if you really want to test for null, use getOrElse(null) instead of get().

Comment: The thing is that I can not mock Lobby class as I need to validate many things on Lobby object variables after this line.

Comment: Adjusting my suggestion on answer to reflect this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use **doReturn(Optional.of(yourMockObj)).when(employeeRepository).findById(idToFind);**

Sample Code

```
@Test
@Order(2)
@DisplayName("Test getEmployeeByEmployeeId")
public void test_getEmployeeByEmployeeId() throws EmployeeNotFoundException
{
    // Setup the mock repo
    Long employeeId = 1L;
    Employee e1ForMock = new Employee(employeeId, "Aravinth P", 29, "aravinth.p@email.com");
    doReturn(Optional.of(e1ForMock)).when(employeeRepository).findById(employeeId);
    // Make the service call
    Employee e1ByService = employeeServiceImpl.getEmployeeByEmployeeId(employeeId);
    // Assert the response
    assertNotNull(e1ByService,"Employee with employeeId : "+employeeId+" not found");
    assertEquals(employeeId,e1ByService.getEmployeeId());
    assertEquals(e1ForMock.getName(), e1ByService.getName());
    assertEquals(e1ForMock.getAge(), e1ByService.getAge());
    assertEquals(e1ForMock.getEmail(), e1ByService.getEmail());
}
```